# Why does docker build not use the build cache?

Tags: docker

Every time I change my `Dockerfile`, docker re-runs all of my commands even if I change something at the end of the file. The commands are **not** cached.

Comment: see also https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8330

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case the image my image was based on contained this statement

```
ONBUILD ADD . /some/path
```

That means, no statement in my `Dockerfile` can be cached when my `Dockerfile` changes, because the `ADD . /some/path` is executed just before any of my statements are executed.

In general: if there is an `ADD . /some/path` statement in the `Dockerfile` no statement after that statement can be cached, because the change to the `Dockerfile` invalidates the cache.

**My solution** was to put the files I want to add into a subdirectory `my_data` and then add the content of the subdirectory to the path:

```
ADD my_data /some/path
```

Unfortunately, adding the `Dockerfile` to the `.dockerignore` does not help, because then the `docker build` cannot execute because it does not find the `Dockerfile` and you get the error `Dockerfile was excluded by .dockerignore pattern 'Dockerfile'`

Comment: Would you share why you are using ONBUILD?  I've never seen a good example of this in the wild.  Thanks!

Comment: @seanmcl It is in an image that comes form docker: https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/a30ed3056ee58ca3df4fd5b51e3d30849dcb7e32/2.7/onbuild/Dockerfile see also https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/python/

This allows to just put your python file next to the Dockerfile and you run the app.

Comment: Thanks so much. You saved me from hours of pointless rebuilding because my ADD statement was the first line in the Dockerfile.